# Does such a circuit make sense and will it filter the DC-DC converter noise ripple?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-filtering, butterworth

I have designed a circuit that simulates noise filtering from the output of a DC-DC converter. The filter should be between the output of the converter and the load. It is assumed that the load will not draw more current than 100 mA. I'm going to use a Murata MGJ2D051515SC converter. I have set the critical values with a data sheet.

[image]

In the simulation, the PULSE voltage source produces a 45 kHz waveform. This is a source of the "noise" I want to filter out. I decided to use the 4th order Butterworth lowpass filter, with a cut-off frequency of 5 kHz, which I determined arbitrarily. It's just that at this frequency the output voltage was clean. I don't quite know how to determine (in simulation) the output impedance of the source - I didn't find such information in the DC-DC converter data sheet.

Does such an approach make sense and will it fulfill its assumptions in undemanding applications?

Comment: Try finding a 7.5 mH inductor that doesn't have more than an ohm or two of series resistance and figure out if it's not too big to fit on your PCB.

Comment: I’d expect DC-DC noise to be at rather higher frequencies, maybe 50kHz into the low MHz so you may find that you can manage with somewhat smaller inductor values.  Although looking at the datasheet this part switches at 45-50jHz so you’re probably in the hall park already.  In my experience though those little potted converters can be rather noisy so it might be worth considering a different device if you’re particularly interested in low noise.

Comment: @Frog So I assume that steeper filter with a higher cutoff frequency would be a better choice in terms of ergonomy, right? Right now, the cutoff frequency is 5kHz.

Comment: Be careful of load transients (if you have any), you may get unacceptable overshoot or ringing on a load release for example.  You can add damping if necessary.  The output impedance of the converter will be very small within its loop bandwidth, (where there's sufficient gain) and will basically look like the converter's LC output filter above the loop bandwidth.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I have just did some research and these coils are quite massive..

Comment: @JohnD "basically look like the converter's LC output filter above the loop bandwidth" -  what do you mean by that?

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki Looking back into the output of the converter, you have an output capacitor driven by an inductor.  The capacitor usually dominates above the loop bandwidth, so the output impedance typically looks approximately like your output capacitor.  BUT it depends on the topology, the specifics of your particular setup, etc.  So no substitute for doing the analysis yourself.

Comment: Your simulation shows a 45 kHz AC component, but you said it was 4-5 kHz with a 5kHz filter cut-off frequency. Also, your 10 ns rise and fall times will introduce harmonics of 100 MHz, where parasitic inductance and capacitance of components will become significant.

Comment: @Jerzy Przezdziecki the appropriate cutoff frequency depends on the behaviour of the DC-DC; especially in cases where the load is light or the current changes abruptly you might find some lower-frequency noise.  I don't know whether going to a steeper filter is going to result in significantly smaller inductors either.  I'd suggest profiling the real-world noise and then decide how best to deal with it.

Comment: @PStechPaul it's a my mistake, of course I meant 45kHz noise source. Thanks.

Comment: @PStechPaul Yes, you are right. I need to add a parasitic components to the simulation. In terms of 100 Mhz signal - won't that be removed with the same filter along with lower frequency cutoff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If noise rejection is so critical you're looking at a 4th order filter on your power line, and you only need tens of milliamps, using a separate LDO to generate a low noise analog power rail probably makes sense. At 45 kHz, a basic LDO will give you 20-30 dB rejection, and a good one will give 40-50 dB. You'll lose a little bit of voltage (or have to set the DCDC output a little higher), but get orders of magnitude lower noise.

Comment: If you want low noise, this is the way.  This is what I do for RF circuit power.  Buck converter to desired rail + .5V, then an LDO.  Also, I would increase the output capacitance on your converter (up to 220UF).  That will have a direct effect on the output voltage ripple.  The less ripple you have there, the less you will have after your filter or LDO if you go that route.